# Adobe PDF Extract API (Python) - Getting started?

Tags: python, pdf, sdk, extract, adobe

I am trying to set up the python starter pdf extraction and having difficulty.

I followed the steps on the below link :
https://developer.adobe.com/document-services/docs/overview/pdf-extract-api/quickstarts/python/

There is a code sample 'extract.py' shown in full on the linked page.

Even when I copy it and paste it I get an error message :

```
 credentials = Credentials.service_principal_credentials_builder().with_client_id(os.getenv('PDF_SERVICES_CLIENT_ID')).with_client_secret(os.getenv('PDF_SERVICES_CLIENT_SECRET')).build()
  File "/Users/tomr/Library/Python/3.9/lib/python/site-packages/adobe/pdfservices/operation/auth/service_principal_credentials.py", line 82, in build
    return ServicePrincipalCredentials(self._client_id, self._client_secret)
  File "/Users/tomr/Library/Python/3.9/lib/python/site-packages/adobe/pdfservices/operation/auth/service_principal_credentials.py", line 28, in __init__
    self._client_id = _is_valid(client_id, 'client_id')
  File "/Users/tomr/Library/Python/3.9/lib/python/site-packages/adobe/pdfservices/operation/auth/credentials.py", line 17, in _is_valid
    raise ValueError(f'{name} must not be blank')
ValueError: client_id must not be blank
```

My 'pdfservices-api-creditentials.json' file is in the same directory as my python file, as well as the sample pdf to read.

I have tried entering my ID, and secret manually but still the same error message.

Comment: Well, considering that it gets the data from the OS Environment variables `PDF_SERVICES_CLIENT_ID` and `PDF_SERVICES_CLIENT_SECRET`, what have you done to make sure they have the values you need? Are you launching the script with those explicitly set to the needed values?

Comment: Did you follow step 2 in the guide?